# In C#, my IEnumerator is reset / created anew when entering a method / local function. Why?

Tags: c#, ienumerator, enumerator

Consider this example:

```cs
List<int> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
void DoSomethingWith(IEnumerator<int> e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
}
using(var e = l.GetEnumerator()) {
    DoSomethingWith(e);
    DoSomethingWith(e);
}
```

This snippet outputs:

```
True
1
True
1
```

I expect

```
True
1
True
2
```

because I pass in the same enumerator.

Why is this the case?

Comment: And if create the collection as `var l = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5} as IEnumerable<int>;` then result will be indeed `1,2`

Comment: Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I think Guru Stron has already explained the situation accurately and in detail. I really have nothing to add to his answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`List<T>.Enumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.enumerator?view=net-8.0) returned by [`List<T>.GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getenumerator?view=net-8.0) is a `struct` so passing it by interface will box it (so subsequent invocations will work with different instances copied from the current state). For example the following:

```cs
using(var e = l.GetEnumerator())
{
    e.MoveNext();
    DoSomethingWith(e);
    DoSomethingWith(e);
}
```

Will print:

```
True
2   
True
2
```

So as you can see the original enumerator is not actually reset.

You can either specify the type explicitly in the `using` as interface (so you will box one time and pass the same instance of the enumerator):

```cs
using(IEnumerator<int> e = l.GetEnumerator())
{
    e.MoveNext();
    DoSomethingWith(e);
    DoSomethingWith(e);
}
```

Or change the method to accept `List<int>.Enumerator` and pass it by `ref`:

```cs
void DoSomethingWith(ref List<int>.Enumerator e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
}

var e = l.GetEnumerator();
DoSomethingWith(ref e);
DoSomethingWith(ref e);
```

Or work with collection via interface, since [`IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,667) is implemented explicitly and the boxing will be handled by the implementation:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> lAsEn = l;
using(var e = lAsEn.GetEnumerator()) {
    DoSomethingWith(e);
    DoSomethingWith(e);
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the issue even without boxing though.

Comment: See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oc5zjE

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride it's not boxing that creates the copy but the fact that struct types are passed by value.

Comment: I can prevents OP's behavior if I pass the enumerator struct by ref.

Comment: Precisely - because that passes a reference to the original enumerator instead of passing it by value

Comment: I'm aware that value types are copied, but why should the copy reset the enumerator's state? That is what I don't get.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride fixed. The non-boxing approach has the same problem - `struct` will be passed by value (for some reason missed that when running the updated code) .

Comment: Isn't it just that structs are passed by val, i.e copied, that is the reason for the observation of the "reset". I think boxing doesn't matter here (didn't verify IL)

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride the enumerator isn't reset. There are two copies of the enumerator that both start from scratch. You's need to pass it with the `ref` key keyword to DoSomethingWith in order to use the same enumerator

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride it doesn't reset it, because the original enumerator is never modified. A *copy* of it is passed inside the method. `MoveNext` modifies the copy, not the original

Comment: @lidqy but it's total news to me that whenever I pass a struct to a method all its fields will be reset. I also don't see a default ctor in `List<T>.Enumerator` that would do that. However there is the ctor `internal Enumerator(List<T> list)` that indeed resets the state. But is this one even being called when passing the struct by value?

Comment: Sorry didn't read the otherxcomments,  evrything's already bee said

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride no, nobody said anything will be reset. You get a copy of the unmodified original. That's how you already use all structs. Structs always have a default constructor. When a copy is made, the exact field values are copied. This is nothing new.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride you can, in some case, see different behavior like say the struct contain a class property. Even though the struct is not the same reference the class property inside will still point to the same thing by default if you don't code anything special

Comment: @Serg posted a comment that when you cast the list to `IEnumerable<T>` you actually get the desired behaviour. See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/P0J31I

Comment: I made a simple static class with an extension method saying: `public static IEnumerator<T> GetEnumeratorFromIEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) => enumerable.GetEnumerator();`. Now I can use `myEnumerableThing.GetEnumeratorFromIEnumerable()` to get the "working" enumerator for this case.